# How to unwind two arrays in mongoquery

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this in mongodb:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5490a00879dc6a138dcefb0f"),
"Date" : 20141012,
"Type" : "Twitter",
"Entities" : [ 
    {
        "ID" : 2,
        "Name" : "test1",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 0.1,
            "Neutral" : 12
        }
     }
],
"Topics" : [ 
    {
        "ID" : 1,
        "Name" : "Test2",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 0.5,
            "Neutral" : 1
        }
    }
]
}
```

Now I need to unwind both array Topics and Entities and then I want to group by on date and sum all values for sentiment so I did it as follow:

```
    DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Entities"); 
    unwind.put("$unwind", "$Topics");
    collectionG = db.getCollection("GraphDataCollection");
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$Date");
    groupFields.put("value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));
    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
    AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(where,unwind, groupBy);
```

Now the problem is that for sum of vaues of sentiment just 0 returned but If I remove the following line :

```
    unwind.put("$unwind", "$Topics");
```

it works correctly so my problem is how to unwind two arrays with one aggregation?

Update :

I changed my code as follow :

```
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Entities"); // "$unwind" converts object with array into many duplicate objects, each with one from array
    DBObject unwindT = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Topics"); // "$unwind" converts object with array into many duplicate objects, each with one from array
    collectionG = db.getCollection("GraphDataCollection");
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$Date");
   groupFields.put("value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));
    groupFields.put("value1", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Topics.Sentiment.Value"));
    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(unwind, unwindT);
    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
    AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(where,unwind,unwindT, groupBy,sort);
```

but the problem is as soon as I add the following line :

```
groupFields.put("value1", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Topics.Sentiment.Value"));
```

the numbers for value1 and value that are returned is not correct and I think I am not doing unwinding correctly. can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate approach,

- `Unwind` the `Entities` array.
- `Group` by `_id`, to get the `sum` of `Entities`.
- `Unwind` the `Topics` array.
- `Group` by `_id`, to get the sum of `Topics`.
- `Project` a field to display the sum of `topics` and `entities` sentiment
  values.
- `Group` by `Date` to get the net sum.

This way, the number of documents in each pipeline is minimum and does not involve and too many self joins.

Aggregation Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$Entities"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "Date":{$first:"$Date"},
         "Topics":{$first:"$Topics"},
         "EntitiesSum":{$sum:"$Entities.Sentiment.Value"}}},
{$unwind:"$Topics"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "Date":{$first:"$Date"},
         "EntitiesSum":{$first:"$EntitiesSum"},
         "TopicsSum":{$sum:"$Topics.Sentiment.Value"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"Date":1,"EntitiesSum":1,"TopicsSum":1,
           "indSum":{$add:["$EntitiesSum","$TopicsSum"]}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$Date",
         "EntitiesSentimentSum":{$sum:"$EntitiesSum"},
         "TopicsSentimentSum":{$sum:"$TopicsSum"},
         "netSentimentSum":{$sum:"$indSum"}}}
])
```

The Java Equivalent:

```
     DBObject unwindEntities = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$Entities");

     DBObject groupSameIdEntities = new BasicDBObject("_id","$_id");
     groupSameIdEntities.put("Date", new BasicDBObject("$first","$Date"));
     groupSameIdEntities.put("Topics", new BasicDBObject("$first","$Topics"));
     groupSameIdEntities.put("EntitiesSum", 
                    new BasicDBObject("$sum","$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));


     DBObject unwindTopics = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$Topics");

     DBObject groupSameIdTopics = new BasicDBObject("_id","$_id");
     groupSameIdTopics.put("Date", new BasicDBObject("$first","$Date"));
     groupSameIdTopics.put("EntitiesSum", 
                         new BasicDBObject("$first","$EntitiesSum"));
     groupSameIdTopics.put("TopicsSum",
                        new BasicDBObject("$sum","$Topics.Sentiment.Value"));

     DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id",0);
     project.put("Date",1);
     project.put("EntitiesSum",1);
     project.put("TopicsSum",1);
     project.put("netSumPerId",
             new BasicDBObject("$add",
                   new String[]{"$EntitiesSum","$TopicsSum"}));

     DBObject groupByDate = new BasicDBObject("_id","$Date");
     groupByDate.put("EntitiesSentimentSum", 
                     new BasicDBObject("$sum","$EntitiesSum"));
     groupByDate.put("TopicsSentimentSum", 
                     new BasicDBObject("$sum","$TopicsSum"));
     groupByDate.put("netSentimentSum", 
                      new BasicDBObject("$sum","$netSumPerId"));

     AggregationOutput output = col.aggregate(unwindEntities,
                                new BasicDBObject("$group",
                                             groupSameIdEntities),
                                unwindTopics,
                                new BasicDBObject("$group",groupSameIdTopics),
                                new BasicDBObject("$project",project),
                                new BasicDBObject("$group",groupByDate));
```

Sample o/p(With two document):

```
{ "_id" : 2.0141012E7, 
"EntitiesSentimentSum" : 0.30000000000000004 ,
"TopicsSentimentSum" : 1.2 , 
"netSentimentSum" : 1.5}
```

Do save date fields as `ISODate()`.

Comment: Thank u @BatScream, A quick question why do u use this line :  groupSameIdTopics.put("Type", new BasicDBObject("$first","$Type")); and what is netSentimentSum?

Comment: In case you want to have a sum of all the entities and topics sentiment values for a date, you could use that field or just ignore it and remove it from the project stage. The type and the other values from the documents are added just to depict that you could include those fields as well but in this case they are not necessary and you may exclude those fields.

Comment: Thank u, Also when I try your code I get the following error:The method aggregate(DBObject, DBObject...) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (List<DBObject>) for line :AggregationOutput output = col.aggregate(stages);  it seems that the number of parameters does not match

Comment: @HamedMinaee That is because, you are using the older version of the Java MongoDB Driver, where the method `aggregate(List<DBObject> param)` is not introduced. I have modifed my answer. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

this is the mongo query (not java):

```
// if you want the sum of Entities and Topics together 
db.test.aggregate(
   [
     {
         $unwind : '$Entities'
     },
     {
         $unwind : '$Topics'
     },     
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: {'Date' : '$Date'},
           sum: { $sum: { $add : ['$Entities.Sentiment.Value', '$Topics.Sentiment.Value']} }
         }
     }
   ]
)

// if you want separated sum
db.test.aggregate(
   [
     {
         $unwind : '$Entities'
     },
     {
         $unwind : '$Topics'
     },     
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: {'Date' : '$Date'},
           value1: { $sum: '$Entities.Sentiment.Value'},
           value2: { $sum: '$Topics.Sentiment.Value'}
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Java:

```
// if you want the sum of Entities and Topics together 
private static void sumOfTopicsAndEntities(DBCollection coll) {
    DBObject unwind1 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Entities");
    DBObject unwind2 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Topics");

    // Now the $group operation
    ArrayList fileds = new ArrayList();
    fileds.add("$Entities.Sentiment.Value");
    fileds.add("$Topics.Sentiment.Value");

    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$Date");
    BasicDBObject add = new BasicDBObject( "$add", fileds);

    groupFields.put("sum", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", add));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

    // run aggregation
    AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(unwind1, unwind2, group);

    // result: { "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "result" : [ { "_id" : 2.0141012E7 , "sum" : 0.6}] , "ok" : 1.0}
    System.out.println(output);
}

// if you want separated sum
private static void seperatedValues(DBCollection coll) {
    DBObject unwind1 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Entities");
    DBObject unwind2 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Topics");

    // Now the $group operation
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$Date");      
    groupFields.put("value1", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));
    groupFields.put("value2", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Topics.Sentiment.Value"));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

    // run aggregation
    AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(unwind1, unwind2, group);

   // result: { "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "result" : [ { "_id" : 2.0141012E7 , "value1" : 0.1 , "value2" : 0.5}] , "ok" : 1.0}
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer but do you know how can I do that with java driver?

Comment: I'm a c# developer, but I updated the answer, its unteste and may have some errors

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work but I got clue from what u did I will update the post (still there is one tiny problem)

Comment: @hamed-minaee, I installed the eclipsed and tested the java code and both working fine. I updated my answer with 2 approaches. I hope it works for you now

Comment: You fell into the trap. The data presented by @HamedMinaee along with the question does not truly highlight the problem, which is what happens when the second array has more than one item in it after you just unwound the first array? There is a different approach to handling that.

Comment: Indeed, as it has been stated by @NeilLunn unwinding the two arrays like that will result in a cartesian product, which I suppose is not what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy query to get wrong, as with most things it's all in the details and you should thoroughly test. A good source for good test cases is varied data with varied conditions, and the clear mistake here is that as a sample there is only one array item presented per array.

In the real world, the reason why these fields are arrays is because you intend to have more than one entry in them. For this reason, simply processing two [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline stages does not work as it would multiply reproduce items in the first array by the number of items in the second array for each document.

So a better test data representation to consider this would be as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5490a00879dc6a138dcefb0f"),
    "Date" : 20141012,
    "Type" : "Twitter",
    "Entities" : [
            {
                    "ID" : 2,
                    "Name" : "test1",
                    "Sentiment" : {
                            "Value" : 0.1,
                            "Neutral" : 12
                    }
            }
    ],
    "Topics" : [
            {
                    "ID" : 1,
                    "Name" : "Test2",
                    "Sentiment" : {
                            "Value" : 0.5,
                            "Neutral" : 1
                    }
            },
            {
                    "ID" : 3,
                    "Name" : "Test3",
                    "Sentiment" : {
                            "Value" : 0.4,
                            "Neutral" : 1
                    }
            }
    ]
}
```

To do this properly with two arrays in the document, you need to discern the entries by type and only add the specific members. First the commented JSON serialized form for easier reading:

```
[
    // Unwind both arrays, produces duplicates
    { "$unwind": "$Entities" },
    { "$unwind": "$Topics" },

    // Add another field to discern type as an array
    { "$project": {
        "Date": 1,
        "Entities": 1,
        "Topics": 1,
        "select": { "$literal": [ "E", "T" ] }
    }},

    // Unwind that array as well
    { "$unwind": "$select" },


    // Group in documents by individual array ID values and per select condition
    // makes everything unique again
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "Date": "$Date",
            "innerId": {
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$select", "E" ] },
                   "$Entities.ID",
                   "$Topics.ID"
               ]
            }
        },
        "value": {
            "$first": {
                "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$select", "E" ] },
                   "$Entities.Sentiment.Value",
                   "$Topics.Sentiment.Value"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},

    //Now just sum the values per date grouping
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.Date",
        "value": { "$sum": "$value" }
    }}
])
```

There is another slightly longer winded approach to this, but I presume that the inner array "ID" field values are unique, at least within the document and that should be fine. The whole process really is essentially combining two separate document properties into one singular field, and dealing with the fact these are arrays.

So you pull the arrays apart, mark each document with an alternate type and further duplicate them again. Now for what is essentially per document and per array member, you inspect the matching type and pick from the appropriate array value. At this point there is now a single document per array member and a singular "value" field, holding the respective value from `*.Sentiment.Value` depending on which field was selected, but the overall point is all the values are there now and not duplicated. All you them do is just sum up the value field for the result.

In fact the main lesson to learn here is you **should** be recording this as a single array in the first place, with a structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5490a00879dc6a138dcefb0f"),
    "Date" : 20141012,
    "Type" : "Twitter",
    "Data" : [
            {
                    "ID" : 2,
                    "Name" : "test1",
                    "Sentiment" : {
                            "Value" : 0.1,
                            "Neutral" : 12
                    },
                    "Class": "Entity"
            },
            {
                    "ID" : 1,
                    "Name" : "Test2",
                    "Sentiment" : {
                            "Value" : 0.5,
                            "Neutral" : 1
                    },
                    "Class": "Topic"
            },
            {
                    "ID" : 3,
                    "Name" : "Test3",
                    "Sentiment" : {
                            "Value" : 0.4,
                            "Neutral" : 1
                    },
                    "Class": "Topic"
            }
    ]
}
```

Which would be a simple matter of processing [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) once on the single array and just summing all the values. If you wanted to work with the data "Class" separately, then you can either filter it or use conditionals. But it's much easier for most operations to simply structure in this way instead.

Translating this to Java is trivial, but just in case you get lost in the process:

```
    DBObject unwind1 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Entities");
    DBObject unwind2 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Topics");

    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project",
        new BasicDBObject( "Date", 1 )
            .append( "Entities", 1)
            .append( "Topics", 1)
            .append( "select", 
                new BasicDBObject( "$literal", new String[]{ "E", "T" })
            )
        );

    DBObject unwind3 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "select");

    DBObject group1 = new BasicDBObject("$group",
        new BasicDBObject("_id",
           new BasicDBObject("_id","$_id")
                .append("Date", "$Date")
                .append("innerId",
                    new BasicDBObject("$cond",
                        new Object[]{
                            new BasicDBObject("$eq", new String[]{"$select", "E"}),
                            "$Entities.ID",
                            "$Topics.ID"
                        }
                    )
                )
        )
        .append("value",
            new BasicDBObject("$first",
                new BasicDBObject("$cond",
                    new Object[]{
                        new BasicDBObject("$eq", new String[]{"$select", "E"}),
                        "$Entities.Sentiment.Value",
                        "$Topics.Sentiment.Value"
                    }
                )
            )
        )
    );

    DBObject group2 = new BasicDBObject("$group",
        new BasicDBObject("_id", "$_id.Date")
            .append("value", new BasicDBObject("$sum","$value"))
    );

    AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(unwind1,unwind2,project,unwind3,group1,group2);
```

One more note. Though you probably should be there by now, the [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator was introduced in MongoDB 2.6 and greater versions. For earlier server versions, there is an undocumented **`$const`** operator which is actually the same thing. Just interchange the code if this must possibly run against an earlier server version of MongoDB.